# delete specific line numbers from history

Tags: python

The command `grep -n blink  ~/.bash_history` outputs all lines that contain `blink`. I need a command that outputs **only** line numbers and executes the line numbers over `history -d linenum`
In python:

```
#list generated from command
linenumbers = [1,2,3,4,5]
for count in range(linenumbers):
   os.system("history -d {}".format(count))
```

How do I do this?

Comment: So you want just the numbers from `~/.bash_history` for lines that contain `blink`?

Comment: You should choose one tech and stick with it. "Answers can be in bash or Python" is not very helpful. I edited it to Python, since that's what your example is...

Comment: @Eric Renouf correct | Carpetsmoker  Alright. The only easy solutions I found were in bash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In bash:

```
for offset in $(history | awk '/blink/ {print $1}' | tac)
do
    history -d $offset
done
```

You can get the offsets directly from the `history` command, no need to generate line numbers with `grep`. Also you need to delete the lines in reverse (hence use of `tac`), because the offset of the commands following the one being deleted are shifted down.